# Is it possible to specify a context property placeholder at runtime

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a standalone jar that uses spring. The config in my spring xml uses placeholders of which I've been replacing when compiling with maven. Example spring config:

```
<bean id="foo" class="package.Foo">
    <property name="host" value="${db.host}" />
</bean>
```

Instead of replacing `${db.host}` using maven I'd like to pass in a properties file at runtime, e.g.

```
java -jar Application.jar productionDB.properties
```

This would allow me to switch the db host at runtime by passing in the production db properties file or the testing db properties file.

Is it possible to do this or are there any better ways of achieving the same goal?

Comment: Using datasource xml might be a good idea to change databse

Comment: Can you share the applicationcontext configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify your property file as a System Property, e.g.:

```
java -jar Application.jar -DappConfig=/path/to/productionDB.properties
```

Then you should be able to reference that in your application context:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${appConfig}"/>

<bean id="foo" class="package.Foo">
    <property name="host" value="${db.host}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to use a `.properties` file to pass in the required variables.

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:productionDB.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can leave your bean declaration as is. The properties will be automatically taken from the `productionDB.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

1. Set your resources via your container's JNDI and use Spring's `<jee:jndi-lookup/>`.
2. Use Spring's `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/myProps.properties" />`.  I prefer this short-hand over the "full" bean definition because Spring will automatically use the correct implementation (`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for Spring < 3.1, or `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` for Spring 3.1+).  Using this configuration, you would just drop the `myProps.properties` at the root of your classpath (`${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib` for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the values using the context:property-placeholder. So your setup would be something like:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file://opt/db.properties"/>
```

Then when you are wiring up your Foo service, you can use the property names in your config, such as

```
<bean id="foo" class="package.Foo">
   <property name="host" value="${db.host}" />
</bean>
```

Then just  use the different set of files for each environmnet

See the [spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) docs for more details.