# How to configure application context in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have application context file, which has such strings:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location">
                <value>main.properties</value>
            </property>
</bean>
```

Here main.properties is file with dynamic properties. I want change their periodically and so I need store these properties on file system, out of the jar.

How can I configure several paths in application context?
Or there is a different way to resolve my issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Spring has very good documentation on their Framework. You should see the guideline and adapt it to your beans and hibernate settings.

Comment: You could use [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15880609/69875).

Comment: okay, thanks a lot every one. I will try implement it.

Comment: Jonathan, I think it's good for me. But I don't understand how to "${db.host}" related with -DappConfig=/path/to/productionDB.properties? How to jvm understand that path to properties is related with "${db.host}" parameter.

Comment: In the example `db.host` would be an entry in the given property file, e.g. `db.host=localhost` etc... You can just ignore that. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to specify a context property placeholder at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880081/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-context-property-placeholder-at-runtime)

Comment: I did so :<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>"file:${appConfig}"</value>
        </property>
    </bean>, but during running myapp, I get "xception: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundExc
eption: class path resource ["file:${appConfig}"] cannot be opened because it do
es not exist"

Comment: I found error. I should to write so:java DappConfig=/path/to/productionDB.properties -jar Application.jar

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="placeholderProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:config/main.properties</value>
            <value>file:config/database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```